# Get ONLY word count from PDF document

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I was hoping to get just the word count from a pdf document programmatically.

I've looked at PDFSharp, but it's awefully bulky for what I want to do.  I don't have access to the server, so I can't install acrobat to get to their api's or anything.  I'd be willing to do it in iTextSharp or another tool.

Comment: What type of success rate are you looking for?  I've had problem in the past with pdfs being created from scanned images which basically requires OCR at some point, which has it's own set of problems

Comment: The success rate is not critical... This is for a translation site that's making a best guess at a translation quote.  The ToU has verbiage all over it saying the quote isn't a contract.  Also, usually in that industry, images are not considered "translatable" (it's a very intolerant industry).  :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iTextSharp has a wonderful `PdfTextExtractor` object that will get you all of the text (assumming as @Rob A pointed out that its actually stored as text and not images or pure vector). Once you've got all of the text a simple RegEx will give you the word count.

The code below should do it for you. (Tested on iText 5.1.1.0)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string InputFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "Input.pdf");

            //Get all the text
            string T = ExtractAllTextFromPdf(InputFile);
            //Count the words
            int I = GetWordCountFromString(T);

        }

        public static string ExtractAllTextFromPdf(string inputFile)
        {
            //Sanity checks
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputFile))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("inputFile");
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(inputFile))
                throw new System.IO.FileNotFoundException("Cannot find inputFile", inputFile);

            //Create a stream reader (not necessary but I like to control locks and permissions)
            using (FileStream SR = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                //Create a reader to read the PDF
                iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(SR);

                //Create a buffer to store text
                StringBuilder Buf = new StringBuilder();

                //Use the PdfTextExtractor to get all of the text on a page-by-page basis
                for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
                {
                    Buf.AppendLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, i));
                }

                return Buf.ToString();
            }
        }
        public static int GetWordCountFromString(string text)
        {
            //Sanity check
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
                return 0;

            //Count the words
            return System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(text, "\\S+").Count;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hass: Awesome, I'll plug this in tonight and mark it answered... To @peer: I'm gonna go open source if I can at this point...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a pdf2text tool and then count the words:

[tools pdf2text](http://www.google.nl/search?q=pdf2text&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

Comment: Thanks, mentioned above that I"m gonna try to go open source... But to my question, this is light weight.