# How to Count total number of Words in PDF?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, itext, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

I am used Adobe Acrobat javascript inbuilt function **getPageNumWords()** it return the number of words present in specified page, but while am copy and paste text content  from PDF file to MS Word, Words count given by MS Word is little bit differ, so any one know in which aspect Acrobat count the words?

Which words count result is correct?

Shall is go with Acrobat Words count result or MS Words count result?

But I want to count the total number of words  in PDF file (my input is PDF file) else can I go with iText?

Words count in PDf using iText is possible?

Comment: Who and why given me -1 vote? please comment what is wrong in my question?

Comment: The reason your counts are different are that PDFs don't actually have any concept of "words". Instead, Acrobat looks for characters that are near to each other and just guesses that these are "words". Further, are page numbers in the footer "words"? PDFs don't actually have footers but Adobe might have some smarts that guess that those should be ignored. Same with the header. Numeric headers in a list? PDFs don't have those either. See this post for a very simplistic version of counting words in iTextSharp http://stackoverflow.com/a/6735846/231316

Comment: @Chris Haas, No no my PDFs don’t contain any header, footer and page number too, it contain simple plain text only, any how I understood that I want to do some extra work to count the no of words, thanks for your useful link, comparing with Acrobat iText extracting text content from PDF with in short time(Quickly), so I go with iText.

Comment: It has already been said that Acrobat has it own meaning for "word". A "word" is essentially a series of characters which appear to belong together (by having the same distance, or by having their bounding box touching). I have seen that kerning already can make a string we would consider to be a word turn into two Acrobat "words". There is an option in the getPageNthWord() method which takes into account non-alphanumeric characters following the string, but that will not help much in your case. So, if you can export text properly, you may go along that path.

Comment: Words in a PDF drawn spaced out may be indistinguishable from multiple single letter "words".

Comment: That shouldn't be too difficult to investigate, should it? Simply extract all text from the input PDF (Acrobat Javascript will allow you to do that as well if I remember well) and see what Acrobat makes of it. This should give you a feeling for what words aren't actual words or why the counts differ.